# C# polymorphism and templates

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

This question may have been asked already, but I don't know the correct question to ask in order to find the answer.

I am attempting to make a set of classes (tags) that hold a value and allow other components to access the value.

The value is generic, which will allow you to create a Tag of any type.  However I need to be able to hold the tags within a list or other data structure to allow the component to have multiple tags of multiple types.

```
  public abstract class BaseTag
  {
    protected object _value;
    public ushort DataQuality { get; protected set; }
    public virtual object Value => _value;
    public abstract void SetValue(object value, ushort dataQuality = 0);
  }

  public class Tag<T> : BaseTag
  {
    public new T Value
    {
      get => (T)_value;
      private set
      {
        _value = value;
      }
    }
    public override void SetValue(object value, ushort dataQuality = 0)
    {
      Monitor.Enter(_tagSync);

      try
      {
        //If value or quality haven't changed, then do nothing
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals((T)_value, (T)value) && dataQuality == DataQuality)
          return;

        DataQuality = dataQuality;
        Value = (T)value;
      }
      finally
      {
        Monitor.Exit(_tagSync);
      }
    }
  }
```

I don't even really know if I am asking the correct question still.

Can anyone help

How do I get the ability to have a 
List tags;
tags[0].Value  <- would like this to call the child value, but it doesn't, it returns the basetag._value, but of type object, not type

Is there an easier better way to make this happen?

Comment: Could you expand upon your question a bit? Do you want Tag<T>.Value to override BaseTag.Value? So that tags[0] would return a object of type T instead of 'object'?

Comment: The only list that can hold any tag is `List<BaseTag>` (exluding the obvious `List<object>`) because that is the only commonality you can use. How do you expect to leverage any concrete type informatión in your code (compile time information) of `myListOfTags[0]` if you'll only have that type information at runtime? The only information you can use at compile time will be the one provided by the common type `BaseTag`.

Comment: `How do I get the ability to have a List tags; tags[0].Value <- would like this to call the child value, but it doesn't` well, actually child class `Tag<T>.Value` returns parents `Base._value`. Should it be something else?

Comment: The issue isn't that it is returning the basetag._value  The issue is that the tag.Value casts to <T> and the basetag doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you really need the `BaseTag` class?

You can convert it to the interface and do with explicit interface declaration like below:

```cs
public interface IBaseTag
{
    object Value { get; }
    ushort DataQuality { get; }
}

public class Tag<T> : IBaseTag
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    object IBaseTag.Value => Value; // explicit interface implementation

    public ushort DataQuality { get; protected set; }

    public virtual void SetValue(T value, ushort dataQuality = 0)
    {
        //If value or quality haven't changed, then do nothing
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(Value, value) && dataQuality == DataQuality)
            return;

        DataQuality = dataQuality;
        Value = (T)value;
    }
}
```

I've skipped the `_tagSync` functional.

Then you can get the

```
var b = new Tag<int>(); //child
IBaseTag a = b; //parent

//a.Value and b.Value are both accessible and can be used
if (b.Value.Equals(a.Value) && a.DataQuality == b.DataQuality)
    return;
```

You can use the `IBaseTag.Value` or `Tag<>.Value` in the same time according to the dependency isolation.

Comment: I have tried it with an interface, but you cannot compile with that as Tag<T> doesn't implement Value  because it is of type <T> not of type object.

Comment: @leggolosDenrif please check my sample source code with the `IBaseTag` and `Tag<T> : IBaseTag`. It compiles and works

Comment: I missed the implementation of the interface value.  I will give that a try.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue I didn't know that you could do this.